# How to allow access-controll-allow-origin with springboot

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using angularjs in the frontend and I'm trying to reach a distant server (tomcat) that is implemented with springboot on my project's backend.

However I'm facing this error:

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.**

I tried to fix this, still having the same issu.

Here's the frontend code:

var services = angular.module('TestService', []);

services.factory('TestService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

```
var factory = {
        add: add
    };

    return factory;

    function add(body) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            };

            $http({
                headers: headers,
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8081/test/add',
                dataType: 'json',

                data: body
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
                console.log('Service works');
                console.log(response.data);
            }, function(errResponse) {
                console.log("erreur");
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

And here's my backend code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import fr.edf.sdin.mrs.recherche.model.entities.ResultEntity;
import fr.edf.sdin.mrs.recherche.service.TestService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@CrossOrigin(origins="*",maxAge=3600, methods={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.OPTIONS,RequestMethod.DELETE}, allowedHeaders={"x-requested-with", "accept", "authorization", "content-type"}, 
exposedHeaders={"access-control-allow-headers", "access-control-allow-methods", "access-control-allow-origin", "access-control-max-age", "X-Frame-Options"},allowCredentials="false",value="/test")
public class TestController{

    @Autowired 
    TestService service;
        @PostMapping(value = "/add", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ResultEntity<String>> add (@RequestBody String body, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        //LOGGER.info("Entree dans le controller back");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        System.out.println(body);
        String result = service.add(body);
        System.out.println(result);
        if (result.equals("")) {
            new ResponseEntity<String>("KO", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResultEntity<String>>(new ResultEntity<String>(result), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/add", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete (@RequestBody String body, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        //LOGGER.info("Entree dans le controller back");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
         response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        System.out.println(body);
        String result = service.add(body);
        if (result.equals("")) {
            new ResponseEntity<String>("KO", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when

1. Server does not allow cross domain headers.
2. Application does not allow cross domain headers.
3. Custom headers provided by request is not accepted by the application.

[Refer](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/10/springboot-no-access-control-allow-origin-ajax-call.html)

Comment: I think it's a problem comming from the server, but still can't resolve it.